# What is the difference between Replication and Synchronization?

Tags: mysql, database

In phpMyAdmin there is a tab for configuring **Replication** and one for **Synchronization**.

- What is the difference between **Replication** and **Synchronization**?
- When do you should use the one or the other?

Thanks, Udo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some digging, the answer in the MySQL/phpMyAdmin context is as follows:

- **Synchronization**: Brings 2 DBs in sync (schema and data)
  Note: This is a 1-time process, which can be run every time you would like to sync 2 DBs, but is triggered manually.
- **Replication**: This is used to continuously (automatically) replicate data between 2 DBs. This is done asynchronously, which means that you do not have to have a permanent connection between the 2 DBs.

**Note:**
To setup replication the sequence is this:

- Run **Synchronization** to sync DBs
- Setup **Replication**

Answer (score 4):

Replication is used to describe the event of copying data. Synchronization is continuous (at least one way) replication that maintains consistency between multiple data sources.

From [phpmyadmin.net documentation](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#faq9_1)

> 9.1 How can I synchronize two databases/tables in phpMyAdmin?
>
> You can now synchronize
>   databases/tables in phpMyAdmin using
>   the Synchronize feature. It allows you
>   to connect to local as well as remote
>   servers. This requires you to enter
>   server host name, username, password,
>   port and the name of the database.
>   Therefore you can now synchronize your
>   databases placed on the same server or
>   some remote server.
>
> This feature is helpful for developers
>   who need to replicate their database’s
>   structure as well as data. Moreover,
>   this feature not only helps
>   replication but also facilitates the
>   user to keep his/her database in sync
>   with another database. Other than the
>   full database, certain tables of the
>   databases can also be synchronized.

Comment: The question is tagged [mysql] and [phpmyadmin] -- I have the impression the user is asking for more specific information.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Daniel, I found more specific information and included it and a source link.